# How to set grub password?

Tags: grub, debian-squeeze

How to set grub password in Debian Squeeze?
How to configure the grup entries in Squeeze, I saw few entries in **/etc/default/grub**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't touch `menu.lst` anymore, since it's Grub2 now.

Answer to your question is can be read in chapter 5:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1369019

Grub2 have difference interaction way and configures through scripts which lies in `/etc/grub.d/`. Inside you will find some awesome examples) After change scripts just type `update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The grub configuration resides in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`, and already contains documentation on how to set a password:

```
## password ['--md5'] passwd
# If used in the first section of a menu file, disable all interactive editing
# control (menu entry editor and command-line)  and entries protected by the
# command 'lock'
# e.g. password topsecret
#      password --md5 $1$gLhU0/$aW78kHK1QfV3P2b2znUoe/
# password topsecret
```

Comment: There is no file in /boot/grub/menu.lst, Note I'am using squeeze, I saw the above configuration in debian lenny.